# Самостоятельный характер приложения.

Tags: приложение

Что это такое? Оно может употребляться без главного (определяемого) слова? Или что?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример текста, где встречается такое выражение.

Comment: Вы уверены, что это термин лингвистики? Может, дан документ, а к нему приложение?